# dynamic controls in a List View gets recreated while closing soft key board

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, listadapter, baseadapter

Here is my requirement for my app.
1. I need to display list of items in a list view with a text box and a button for each item.
2. The number of items differ each time while running the app.
3. While clicking the button i need to read the text box content and need to do some task.
4. I Created dynamic text box and buttons in "getView" of Adapter.

**Problem**
1. Problem is After I enter the data in the text box of an list item and closing the soft keyboard, all the text box of list item gets created again and im losing the data which i enetered.
2. Is any other way to create dynamic text box other than in Get view function?
below is my code snippet

```
public class ImageAdaspter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContextL;

    public ImageAdaspter(Context contextP) {
        mContextL = contextP;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return lis.GetLength();
    }

    public Object getItem(int PositionP) {
        return PositionP;
    }

    public long getItemId(int PositionP) {
        return PositionP;
    }

    public View getView(int PositionP, View ConvertViewP, ViewGroup ParentP) {

        RelativeLayout TheRelativelayoutL = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

        TextView textview1 = new TextView(mContextL);
        textview1.setText("HI");
        textview1.setSingleLine(true);
        textview1.setId(2);

        EditText textBox1 = new EditText(mContextL);
        textBox1.setEms(3);
        textBox1.setId(4);

        Button btn1 = new Button(mContextL);
        btn1.setText("Process");
        btn1.setTextSize(10);
        btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do stuff
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sample Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        TheRelativelayoutL.addView(textview1);
        TheRelativelayoutL.addView(textBox1);
        TheRelativelayoutL.addView(btn1);
        return TheRelativelayoutL;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get any solution?

Comment: Not sure of the reasons for views getting recreated and trying to re-create your scenario to investigate the reason behind it. Meanwhile could you try implementing it using a view holder.
Here's a link.    Not sure of the reasons for views getting recreated and trying to re-create your scenario to investigate the reason behind it. Meanwhile could you try implementing it using a view holder.
Here's a link.  http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations